# Get all possible object keys from a list of objects Javascript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object, typescript

I have a list of objects like so:

```
[ 
  { item1: "1", item2: "2" },
  { item1: "3", item2: "4", item3: "5" },
  { item1: "6" },
  { item1: "7", item2: "8", item3: "9", item4: "10" },
]
```

I need to be able to get a list of all the possible keys:

```
["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4" ]
```

I tried using `Object.Keys` but this requires me to specify a specific object, the problem is, the list is made dynamically so the keys and values are unknown by me.

Comment: First you fill the array with all keys.    
Second you filter keys to keep unique keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method.

```js
var data = [{
  item1: "1",
  item2: "2"
}, {
  item1: "3",
  item2: "4",
  item3: "5"
}, {
  item1: "6"
}, {
  item1: "7",
  item2: "8",
  item3: "9",
  item4: "10"
}, ];

var res = data.reduce(function(arr, o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce(function(a, k) {
    if (a.indexOf(k) == -1) a.push(k);
    return a;
  }, arr)
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj=[ 
  { item1: "1", item2: "2" },
  { item1: "3", item2: "4", item3: "5" },
  { item1: "6" },
  { item1: "7", item2: "8", item3: "9", item4: "10" },
],
  keys=[];
  obj.forEach(function(element){
    for (var key in element) {
        if(keys.indexOf(key)===-1){
          keys.push(key);
         }
    }
  });
  console.log(keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for collecting the keys.

```js
var obj = [{ item1: "1", item2: "2" }, { item1: "3", item2: "4", item3: "5" }, { item1: "6" }, { item1: "7", item2: "8", item3: "9", item4: "10" }],
    items = obj.reduce((s, o) => [...new Set([...s, ...Object.keys(o)])], []);

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should iterate through the list and get array of keys when if you find a longer element than the current

```
var obj=[ 
  { item1: "1", item2: "2" },
  { item1: "3", item2: "4", item3: "5" },
  { item1: "6" },
  { item1: "7", item2: "8", item3: "9", item4: "10" },
]
var maxLength = 0;
var keys = [];
for (var i = yourArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(Object.keys(obj[i]).length > maxLength){
        maxLength = Object.keys(obj[i]).length;
        keys = Object.keys(obj[i])
    }

}
```